# How to restore an application level variable

Tags: android

We have savedInstanceState for Activity and Fragment, and restore it when the app came back to alive.

But at times the application level also got killed as per [this article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/dont-keep-activities-alone-is-not-enough-for-testing-407b7c01bd60.)

Is there a way to restore application-level variables?

Note: I'm not using SharedPreference of Database, as I don't need to restore the value if it is killed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ApplicationLifecycleCallbacks` as below. It will do the work, but I think it is overkill, as it get saved every time an activity perform a save

```
class MainApplication: Application() {

    companion object {
        const val APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY = "application_bundle"
        var myStoredVariable = false
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{
            override fun onActivityCreated(
                activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                savedInstanceState?.apply {
                    myStoredVariable = getBoolean(APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY)
                }
            }
            override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {}
            override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(
                activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
                savedInstanceState.putBoolean(APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY, myStoredVariable)
            }
            override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823503/3286489 is more verbatim of what's possible.

But with some helper class created in [here](https://github.com/elye/demo_android_application_lifecycle/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/applicationlifecycle/ActivityLifecycleHandler.kt), we can have `onSavedInstanceState` at the application level as shown below

```
class MainApplication: Application(), 
    ActivityLifecycleHandler.LifecycleListener {

    companion object {
        const val APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY = "application_bundle"
        var myStoredVariable = false
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
            ActivityLifecycleHandler(this))
    }

    override fun onApplicationCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        savedInstanceState?.apply {
            myStoredVariable = getBoolean(APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY)
        }
    }

    override fun onApplicationSaveInstanceState(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(
            APPLICATION_SAVE_KEY, myStoredVariable)
    }
}
```

You can get more detail on the code in [this article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/making-saving-android-application-state-possible-d1012696a987?sk=b24a540ecf6ed82b9e0d1ba1736f4a28)